# Difference-in-difference in panel data

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, causality, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

Under which conditions should we expect the difference-in-difference estimate to be equal to the equivalent panel data model?

Strictly speaking, whenever we have a experiment that offers a well defined treated and control groups in two periods of time, for using difference-in-difference methods, people recommend running OLS of models such as:

```
Stata:

reg y post treatment postXtreatment

and the coefficient on "postXtreatment" would represent the treatment effect 

At the same time, in case we have panel data for two periods we can run:

xi: xtreg y i.year postXtreatment, fe
```

When exactly should we expect equivalence? Does it have anything to do with the panel being balanced?

Just one more question, in case we have more years available is the fixed effect model in the fashion the described above a good way to infer the treatment effect?

Comment: Should be completely identical with two treatment groups and two time periods.

Comment: The xtreg command is missing the main effect for treatment. Also, Stata can handle creating the interaction term. For example, "reg y post##treatment" would be the Stata way of doing the first model and "xtreg y post##treatment, fe" would be Stata way of doing the second.

Comment: Also, neither of these are accounting for the dependent (clustered) nature of the data given repeated measurement. This is what xtreg or mixed help you do that reg doesn't do. However, you need to specify the cluster variable (person id).

Comment: See http://errickson.net/stats-notes/xtsetvsmixed.html

Comment: The models are specified correctly. xtreg with fixed effects does account for the clustered nature of the data, by including fixed effects for each participant. In doing so it controls for all between person bias. This is why the model correctly does NOT include a main effect for treatment: that variable would drop out of the model due to collinearity with the fixed effect. Running a model with random effects (via mixed or xtreg, re) would NOT be equivalent to a DinD model because it would not fully account for between-person differences.

Answer (score 0):

You would expect equivalence when T = 2. If you have more than 2 years, use the latter approach (the one that relies on fixed effects). Please see http://econ.lse.ac.uk/staff/spischke/ec533/did.pdf for more. Note: `xi:` is redundant in the newer versions of Stata.

Comment: Not really.. As long as you don't include covariates, the diff-in-diff estimator is equivalent to the two-way fixed effects model

Answer (score 0):

As long as the treatment occurs at the same time for all units, the estimator of DiD is equivalent to the one from panel data (usually called Two-way fixed effects), as shown by Jeffrey Wooldridge in [this paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3906345), section 5. To show it, we can generate some random data, apply an effect and estimate with both methods.

```
np.random.seed(1)
n=10 #number of units
ID=np.arange(n) #list of IDs
t= 10 #periods of time 

#Create dataset
data=pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.tile(ID,t),'year':np.repeat(np.arange(t),n),
                   'after_treatment':(np.repeat([0,1],n*t/2)),'treatment':np.zeros(n*t)})
data.loc[data['ID']<3, 'treatment']=1 #Mark these units as treated in the dataset
data['interaction']=data['after_treatment']*data['treatment'] #Create interaction variable
ui= np.random.normal (0,2,n*t) #Error term centered in zero with constant variance
data['out']=2*data['after_treatment']+2*data['treatment']+3*data['interaction']+ui #generate outcome
```

First, let's estimate with the classic diff-in-diff equation:
$$Y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \textrm{Post}_t + \beta_2 \textrm{Treated}_i + \beta_3 \textrm{Treated}_i  \textrm{Post}_t + e_{it}$$

```
print(smf.ols('out~after_treatment*treatment', data=data).fit().params[3])
```

The result is 2.8685.
If we estimate as a panel data including time and unit-fixes effects, we are doing:

$$y_{it}=\alpha_{i}+ \gamma_{t} +\tau_{it}TreatedxPost +\epsilon_{it}$$

```
df_panel=data.set_index(['ID', 'year'])
Y=df_panel["out"] #Dependent variable
X=df_panel[[ "interaction"]] #Independent variables
X=sm.add_constant(X) #adding constant
model=PanelOLS(Y,X, entity_effects=True, time_effects=True).fit()
print(model.params[1])
```

The result is the same, 2.8685